# Using mixins in material-ui to customize components in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, material-ui

I am trying to customize a textfield component in Material-ui with React.

According information from [this page](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-textfield):

> To customize the colors of any part of the text-field, use the following mixins. We recommend you apply these mixins within CSS selectors like .foo-text-field:not(.mdc-text-field--focused) to select your unfocused text fields, and .foo-text-field.mdc-text-field--focused to select your focused text-fields. To change the invalid state of your text fields, apply these mixins with CSS selectors such as .foo-text-field.mdc-text-field--invalid.

I tried to use this mixin to changed the color of the border:

`mdc-text-field-outline-color($color): Customizes the border color of the outlined text field.`

However, I have no idea how to use this. I installed scss, but I don't get the syntax of setting the color to red with scss.

```
@mixin mdc-text-field-outline-color($color) {

}
```

It seems like I start with something like this, but not sure how to move on without a specific example.

Comment: Just hard to think `material-components` is the same as the current `material-ui`

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.
You can pass `colors` as a `map`. Or pass a single color and use `darken` and `lighten` functions; the choice is yours how you want to pass property values.

#### Example 1

```
@mixin mdc-text-field-outline-color() {
  & {
    &.mdc-text-field--focused {
      border-color: blue;
    }
    &.mdc-text-field--invalid {
      border-color: gray;
    }
    &:not(.mdc-text-field--focused) {
      border-color: black;
    }
  }
}


.foo-text-field {
  @include mdc-text-field-outline-color();
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

#### Example 2

```
@mixin mdc-text-field-outline-color($color) {
  & {
    &:not(.mdc-text-field--focused) {
      border-color: #{$color};
    }
    &.mdc-text-field--focused {
      border-color: darken($color, 20%);
    }
    &.mdc-text-field--invalid {
      border-color: lighten($color, 20%);
    }
  }
}


.foo-text-field {
  @include mdc-text-field-outline-color(#C4C4);
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```